# vscode command line: how to open a project in multiple new windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am using vscode

```
$ code --version
1.32.3
a3db5be9b5c6ba46bb7555ec5d60178ecc2eaae4
x64
```

I have a folder as

```
project
 -- test.txt
```

I want to open `test.txt` along with `project` folder as context

i am trying

```
code -n ~/project/test.txt ~/project/
```

this opens  the file test.txt and also shows the folder `project`

[image]

but when i run it again

```
code -n ~/project/test.txt ~/project/
```

it does not open another new window. it shows the same window

Then i tried

```
code -n ~/project/test.txt -a ~/project/
```

this open new but does not show the project folder

[image]

My requirement is, i want to open `test.txt` in a new window and also show the `project` folder

I can do this in sublime text,

```
subl -a ~/project ~/project/test.txt -n
```

If i run `n` times, it opens `n` new windows with the project folder files shown

The reason i want this is, if the project folder is not open then, `ctrl + P` will not search for all files in `project`

Comment: try move to directory you want to open , then run code .

Comment: `cd ~/project/; code -n test.txt -a .` ran this twice, it opens second new window but without showing the project folder

Comment: `cd ~/project/; code .`

Comment: same behaviour, no change

Comment: I think this is raised in github `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2686`. But its long time ago. Whats the recent status i dont konw

Comment: your VSC version is >20 editions behind the latest

Comment: i will upgade it